# complicated htaccess 301 redirect: change dashes to plus sign, remove .html, and shorten?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I need to change this url using htaccess rewrite from:

```
http://www.athomefitness.com/BH-Fitness-LKT8-Treadmill-p-19769.html
```

to this:

```
http://www.athomefitness.com/?s=BH+Fitness+LKT8+Treadmill
```

So the htaccess would strip off the `-p-19769.html` and change all the dashes to plus signs. Can this be done where there are many pages that end with the `-p-12345.html` ?

Comment: Have you found answer ?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is what you want

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*\.html
RewriteRule (.+)-(.+) $1+$2 [N]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\+p\+[0-9]+\.html$ /?s=$1 [L]
```

1st Rule change - to + in loop, then, when it not found -, 2nd Rule remove +p+...

Comment: Thank you. I'm also wondering if this solution applies the dashes to plus sign only to the urls that end in .html?